# How do you get the largest integer from a set of numbers in c++?

Tags: c++

If you have a group of numbers, like a=4,b=5,c=8. Is there a way to get the program print out the largest value. So, for instance, I have all my values outputted 4,5,8. How can I get the program to output the largest value? (I'm using c++). I used if statements but I feel like there is a shorter way. On Google, I keep finding INT_MAX but doesn't that display the largest number in the int type?

here's part of the code

```
int a = (rand()%6)+1;
int b = (rand()%6)+1;
int c = (rand()%6)+1;
cout << int a << int b << int c << endl; //I'm trying to get it to display the largest int out of this group
```

I deleated my if statements trying to find a better way to display the largest of the group.

Comment: This depends on how you're representing your numbers. Can you [edit] your post to show what you've tried?

Comment: Are your numbers separate variables?

Comment: Put (pointers to) the numbers into an array or other container, and then use [`std::max_element()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) to find the largest value

Comment: [std::max_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) , [std::max](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max)

Answer (score 5):

> How can I get the program to output the largest value?

There are two steps in the process.

1. Compute the maximum of the three numbers.
2. Display the maximum number.

If you are allowed to use functions from the standard libraries, you can use [`std::max`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) to compute the maximum of thee numbers. If you are not, you will have to write one yourself. Assuming you can use `std::max`, your code needs to be:

```
int m = std::max({a, b, c});
cout << "maximum: " << m << endl;
```

It can also be a one-liner.

```
cout << "maximum: " << std::max({a, b, c}) << endl;
```